# What type of plant is this? Spikey stems

Tags: identification

[image]

Anyone know what type of plant this is? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like [Himalayan blackberry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubus_armeniacus) to me. But, hard to say without more details. It would be helpful to know what part of the world this photo was taken, and what time of year.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah they are brambles and they will spread like hell if you don't take measures. They are hard to remove because of the thorns, best is to find some good gloves and use shears to cut off pieces of 30-50 cm.

Comment: What type of brambles though? If it's the fruit producing kind like blackberries I would be happy to let it grow. But I'm not seeing any evidence of that, so I should get rid of it?

Comment: I suspect blackberries, but you'll have to wait and see what kind. You can of course keep them, but my advice is to keep the bush under control. They can take over your garden quickly, and it is a hell of a job to remove them then.